# Google Keep -- how to hack info into Keep using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how I might put a new note into Google Keep using Javascript, e.g. from a Chrome app or extension?  There doesn't seem to be an API, and it's not clear to me how to trick the front end into thinking that I have typed in text or uploaded an image.

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that there is not yet a *published* API, however, take a look here for clues to the *unpublished* API you might be able to use: http://discovery-check.appspot.com/notes/v1